# How to have an object with an array of objects from form in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a 'recipe' object that contains an array of 'ingredients' and their properties when a form is submitted. I created inputs with ng-models: recipe.name, recipe.servings, recipe.ingredients[0].name, recipe.ingredients[0].amount, recipe.ingredients[1].name, recipe.ingredients[1].amount, etc. But when the form is submitted, only recipe.ingredients[0]'s properties are recorded. In my controller, I have the following:

```
angular.module('recipeMavenApp')
  .controller('AddRecipeCtrl', function () {
  var vm = this;
  vm.ingredientCount = 1;
  vm.recipe = {
    name: '',
    servings: 0,
    ingredients: [],
 };

vm.appendIngredient = function() {
  var newIngredientInput = angular.element('<input type="text"' +
  'ng-model="recipe.ingredients[' + vm.ingredientCount + '].name" placeholder="Ingredient name" />' +
  '<input type="number" min="0.25" max="1000" step="0.25" ng-model="recipe.ingredients[' +
  vm.ingredientCount + '].amount" placeholder="Amount"/>');   
   angular.element(document.querySelector('#ingredients')).append(newIngredientInput);
  vm.ingredientCount++;
};

vm.addRecipe = function(recipe) {
  vm.recipe = recipe;
  console.log(vm.recipe); //Testing to see what is received.
};
```

The form:

```
<form novalidate >
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="recipeName">Name of Recipe</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="recipe.name" id="recipeName" required/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="recipeServings">Number of Servings</label>
  <input type="number" min="1" max="50" ng-model="recipe.servings" id="recipeServings"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="ingredients">
  <label for="recipeIngredients">Ingredients</label>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="add.appendIngredient()">Add Ingredient</button>
  <br />
  <input type="text" ng-model="recipe.ingredients[0].name" id="recipeIngredients" placeholder="Ingredient name" />
  <input type="number" min="0.25" max="1000" step="0.25" ng-model="recipe.ingredients[0].amount" placeholder="Amount"/>
  <br/>
</div>
  <button ng-click="add.addRecipe(recipe)" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> Add Recipe</button>
</form>
```

How do I capture all ingredients in the recipe.ingredients array on form submit?

Comment: Could you add some html as well ? Even better, a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Why does everyone always want a fiddle? This doesn't seem that difficult to debug. But you do need to show us the form, not answerable w/out that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to rewrite your code there : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/3cs13L1z/)

I used `ng-repeat` to generate the list of ingredients (where I uses the `$index` for the models) to avoid any DOM manipulation in the controller :

```
<div ng-repeat="ingredient in recipe.ingredients">
  <input type="text" ng-model="recipe.ingredients[$index].name" placeholder="Ingredient name" />
  <input type="number" min="0.25" max="1000" step="0.25" ng-model="recipe.ingredients[$index].amount" placeholder="0"/> 
</div>
```

Based on the model :

```
$scope.recipe = {
  name: '',
  servings: 0,
  ingredients: [{
    name: '',
    amount: null
  }]
};
```

In the `$scope.recipe.ingredients` you can add how many `{name:'', amount:null}` as you need to show by default (you can also add a prefilled name or amount, for instance : `{name:'Ingredient 1', amount:5}`).

Then when I need a new ingredient I just push a new object in the `$scope.ingredients` array :

```
$scope.appendIngredient = function() {
  $scope.recipe.ingredients.push({
    name: '',
    amount: null
  });
};
```

Feel free to let me know if it fulfills your requirements or if you have any question.

Thanks